# How can I create a generic object with defined parameters using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to build a generic base class for an Entity Framework Repository and UnitOfWork class.  I have defined by base repository class as follows:

```
public class EntityRepository<CContext, TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    where CContext : DbContext
{

     protected readonly CContext _DbContext;
     protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> _DbSet;

     public EntityRepository(CContext context)
     {
         this._DbContext = context;
         this._DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
     }

     // Implementation details go here
}
```

I can create typed instance of the repository as follows:

```
var ctx = new ProductContext();
var db = new EntityRepository<ProductContext, Product>(ctx);
```

Although, in practice, a type specific repository would be created for each class in the data context, for example...

```
public class ProductDb
    : EntityRepository<ProductContext, Product>
{
    public ProductDb(ProductContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
```

}

This all seems to work as expected.  My problem lies in my generic UnitOfWork base class.  Previously, I have manually defined each repository property in the UnitOfWork implementation, but I would like to automate this by using a hashtable and reflection (similar to that described in [Long Le's Blog](http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/))

```
public class UnitOfWork<CContext>
    where CContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly CContext _Context;
    protected readonly Hashtable _Repositories;

    public UnitOfWork(CContext context)
    {
       this._Context = context;
       this._Repositories = new Hashtable();
    }

    public EntityRepository<CContext, TEntity> Repository<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;

        if (!_Repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var repositoryType = typeof(EntityRepository<CContext, TEntity>);

            var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(
                repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity))
             );

            _Repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
        }

        return (EntityRepository<CContext, TEntity>)_Repositories[type];
    }
}
```

When I run this code it fails with the error message:

> Product is not a GenericTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this problem, or to put the question another way, how can I create a new instance of my EntityType using reflection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are getting the wrong type. This is wrong because it gets the type of a generic instance.

```
var repositoryType = typeof(EntityRepository<CContext, TEntity>);
```

Use this instead to get the type of the generic.

```
var repositoryType = typeof(EntityRepository<,>);
```

Also you need to change this

```
var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(
                repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(CContext>,typeof(TEntity))
             );
```

Comment: Also pass the context to Activator.CreateInstance() as constructor argument.

Comment: Thank you dburner, much appreciated - that works perfectly.  I hadn't seen the construct typeof(EntityRepository<,>) before - very useful.